# Val(" ") Not Removing Text From Text Box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my HTML file, I have code which takes input in a text box and then displays it on the page without re-loading the page. I am using JQuery to do this. However, the line in the code which is supposed to remove the text from the text box is not working. Please see below.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styleblock.css">
  <script type=text/javascript src="{{url_for('static', filename='jquery.js')}}">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function placetextfromboxes() {
      event.preventDefault();
      var textFrombox = $("#yg").val();
      $("input.submit").val("");
      $("#word").html(textFrombox)
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <p>Name:</p>
    <textarea id="yg" name="nm"></textarea>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit:" onclick="placetextfromboxes(event);" /></p>
    <p id="word"></p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Text from "" is taken to the placetextfromboxes function and put in the variable "textFrombox". However, the line "$("input.submit").val("");" is supposed to erase the text from the box but it is not being erased. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Why not `$("#yg").val("")` ? `$("input.submit")` select nothing, whereas `$("input")` would select the Submit button

Answer (score 3):

As per azro's suggestion in the comments, changing `$("input.submit")` to `$("#yg")` produces the effect you're looking for.

For convenience, the correction is offered in the snippet below.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styleblock.css">
  <script type=text/javascript src="{{url_for('static', filename='jquery.js')}}">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function placetextfromboxes() {
      event.preventDefault();
      var textFrombox = $("#yg").val();
      $("#yg").val("");
      $("#word").html(textFrombox)
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <p>Name:</p>
    <textarea id="yg" name="nm"></textarea>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit:" onclick="placetextfromboxes(event);" /></p>
    <p id="word"></p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

It appeared to me as though `$("input.submit")` had been intended to select the submit button.

Changing the value to `$("input")` or `$("input[type=submit]")` successfully selected it but, as you may guess, it simply erased the text in the button when clicked.

Changing to `$("#yg").val("")`, successfully erases the text in the textarea and does not affect the value stored in the `textFrombox` variable.

Answer (score 2):

`input.submit` would target an `input` element with class `submit`. What you have instead is attribute `type` of value `submit`. Therefore, to select this you'd need to do `input[type=submit]`.

But it looks like you just want `$('#yg').val('')`.